# How To: SVN local and remote repository

Tags: svn, local

So I have been working on a project, and am using SVN with Tortoise SVN client. Since I was working by myself, I just had a local repository, but now we are bringing in a team member, and I want to replicate or clone or whatever you call it, the local repository on Assembla.  What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Make a dump of your local repository and import it into Assembla. https://helpdesk.assembla.com/customer/portal/articles/1604338-subversion-svn-getting-started-guide#a41

Comment: Thanks.  Tortoise does not seem to have as way to make a dump file, so I used SVNadmin